# Find the absolute extrema by Lagrange multipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the absolute extrema for the function $g(x,y)=e^{x^2}-y^2$ on the unit disk $D$ given by:

$D=\{(x,y)|x^2+y^2\le1\}$. Do this by first finding all critical points of and classifying them, then use Lagrange 
multipliers to find maximums or minimums on the boundary of the disk. The absolute extrema will be the largest and 
smallest of these points’ values.

Answer (score 1):

Setting $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1$. We want to maximize and minimize the function $g(x,y)=e^{x^2}-y^2$ subject to the side condition $f(x,y)=0$. The gradients are  $
\nabla g\left( {x,y} \right) = 2xe^{x^2 } {\bf{i}} - 2y{\bf{j}}$ and 
$\nabla f\left( {x,y} \right) = 2x{\bf{i}} + 2y{\bf{j}}$. Use the cross-product formula of Lagrange $\nabla g \times \nabla f=0$ which equivalent to write $$
\frac{{\partial g}}{{\partial x}}\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}} - \frac{{\partial g}}{{\partial y}}\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}} = 0.$$
So that we have $$
\frac{{\partial g}}{{\partial x}}\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}} - \frac{{\partial g}}{{\partial y}}\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}} = \left( {2xe^{x^2 } } \right)\left( {2y} \right) - \left( { - 2y} \right)\left( {2x} \right) = 4xye^{x^2 }  + 4xy = 0
$$
which holds iff $x=0$ or $y=0$. In case $x=0$, from the side condition $x^2+y^2=1$ so that $y=\pm1$. Similarly, in case $y=0$, from the side condition we get $x=\pm1$. Therefore, the point under consideration are $(0,-1),(0,1),(-1,0),(1,0)$. At first two points $f$ takes on the value $0$ and at the last two points $f$ takes on the value $e$. Hence, the first is a minimum and the second is a maximum.

Answer (score 1):

The function $ \ z \ = \ g(x , \ y) \ = \ e^{x^2} - \ y^2 \ $ , because the coordinate variables only appear "squared", has symmetry about the $ \ z-$ axis [if $ \ (x, \ y, \ z ) \ $ is on the surface, so is $ \ (-x, \ -y, \ z ) \ $ ] .  So we can limit ourselves to examining the portion of the surface for which the projection onto the $ \ xy-$ plane is the first-quadrant portion of the unit disk.

I won't go through all of the more usual "Lagrange-multiplier calculation here, since much of it doesn't differ  from what **mwomath** has already done:  the "Lagrange equations" are

$$2 \ x \ e^{x^2} \ = \ \lambda \ \cdot \ 2 \ x \ \ , \ \ -2 \ y \ = \ \lambda \ \cdot \ 2 \ y \  $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \  2 \ x \ ( \lambda \ - \ e^{x^2}) \ = \ 0 \ \ , \ \ 2 \ y \ (1 \ + \ \lambda) \ = \ 0 $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ = \ 0 \ , \ y \ = \ 0 \ , \ \ \text{or} \ \ \lambda \ = \ e^{x^2} \ = \ -1 \ \ , $$

the last of these results offering no solution for $ \ x \ $ .  Any critical points of $ \ g(x , \ y) \ $ therefore lie on the coordinate axes.  Thus the only interior point of the disk which is a critical point is where the axes intersect each other, at the origin $ \ (0, \ 0) \ $ .  The "concavity index" tell us

$$ D \ \vert_{(0,0)} \ = \ [ \ g_{xx} \ g_{yy} \ - \ g_{xy}^2 \ ] \  \vert_{(0,0)} \ = \ [ \ ( 2 \ + \ 4 \ x ) \ e^{x^2} \ \cdot \ (-2) \ - \ 0^2 \ ] \ \vert_{(0,0)} \ = \ -4 \ \ .  $$

So the point $ \ ( 0, \ 0, \ 1 ) \ $ on the surface is a saddle point.  We might have anticipated this conclusion by noting that $  \ g(x , \ 0) \ = \ e^{x^2}  \ $ and $  \ g(0 , \ y) \  = \ 1 - y^2 \ $ , so the cross-sectional curves along the coordinate axes have oppositely-directed concavities.  This behavior of the function surface produces a saddle-point at their intersection.

At this point, we may invoke the the symmetries of the surface and those cross-sectional curves to observe that  $  \ g(x , \ 0) \ $ increases to a **maximum** on the unit circle at $   \ g(1 , \ 0) \ = \ e \ $ (and so also for  $   \ g(-1 , \ 0) \ $ ) and that  $  \ g(0 , \ y) \ $ decreases to a **minimum** at $   \ g(0 , \ 1) \ = \ 0 \ $ (and likewise at $   \ g(0 , \ -1)  \ $ ) .

[image]

It remains to check for critical points on the unit circle itself. It suffices to search along the first quadrant using $ \ y^2 \ = \ 1 \ - \ x^2 \ $ and $  \ g(x , \ y) \ \vert_{\partial D} \ = \ e^{x^2} +  \ x^2 - 1 \ $ .  So a critical point on the circle must satisfy $ \ 2 \ x \ e^{x^2} \ + \ 2 \ x \ = \ 0  $ , which only occurs for $ \ x \ = \ 0 \ $ (which we've already dealt with), so there are no other critical points on the unit circle or the unit disk.

A question of possible interest is why this search didn't pick out the maxima at $ \ (\pm 1, \ 0, \ e) \ $ .  The function $ \ e^{x^2} +  \ x^2 - 1 \ $ that we used is always "concave upward", so its derivative is *not* zero at $ \ x \ = \ \pm 1 \ $ ; we are forced to check these "endpoints" separately.

**EDIT [1/27] --**  (I delayed adding this part because I wasn't satisfied with part of the argument.)  This can also be analyzed using polar coordinates. The function becomes

$$ \ g(r, \ \theta) \ \ =  \ \ e^{r^2 \cos^2 \theta} \ - \ r^2 \ \sin^2 \theta \ \ = \ \ e^{r^2 \cos^2 \theta} \ - \ r^2 \ \cos^2 \theta \ + \ r^2 \ \ . $$

On a ray $ \ \theta \ = \ \theta_0 \ $  extending from the origin, the radial derivative is

$$ \frac{dg}{dr} \ \vert_{\theta_0} \ = \ 2 \ r \ \cos^2 \theta_0 \ e^{r^2 \cos^2 \theta_0} \ - \ 2 \ r \ \cos^2 \theta_0 \ + \ 2 \ r $$ $$ = \ \ 2 \ r \ \left[ \ \cos^2 \theta_0 \ (e^{r^2 \cos^2 \theta_0} \ - \  1 ) \ + \ 1 \ \right] \ \ . $$

The factor $ \ e^{r^2 \cos^2 \theta_0} \ $ is never less than 1 , so the factor in parentheses is non-negative, making the entire factor in brackets greater than or equal to 1 .  So the radial derivative can only be zero for $ \ r \ = \ \ 0 \ $ , indicating that there is only one critical point in the interior of the disk.

Out on the unit circle, $ \ r \ = \ 1 \ $ , the function is  $ \ g(1, \ \theta) \ \ =  \ \ e^{\cos^2 \theta} \ -  \ \cos^2 \theta \ + \ 1 \ $ , for which the angular derivative is

$$ \frac{dg}{d \theta} \ \vert_{r = 1} \ = \ - 2 \ \cos \theta \ \sin \theta \ e^{ \cos^2 \theta} \ + \ 2 \ \cos \theta \ \sin \theta \ \ = \ \ \sin \ 2 \theta \ ( 1 \ - \  e^{\cos^2 \theta}  ) \ \ . $$

In the first quadrant, the factor in parentheses is zero at $ \ \theta \ = \ \frac{\pi}{2} \ $  and $ \ \sin \ 2 \theta \ $ is zero for $ \ \theta \ = \ 0 \ , \ \frac{\pi}{2} \ $ .  So we recover the result found above that the critical points on the unit circle lie at the intersections with the coordinate axes.

[Working with Lagrange multipliers here will lead to the same conclusion.]